# Send Remote AT Command to Xbee Device in MicroPython

Tags: xbee, micropython

I am trying to create a series ZigBee networks. Each network will be in close proximity to another, as such when all devices are turned on I need them to repeatedly look for their specified network and always join it.

To configure the network I have a coordinator device turned on and it will find up to 32 other devices. Once found I want the coordinator to set the remote devices Names ("NI") and PANID ("ID"). After using `xbee.discover()` I have a list of devices in my network. However I can not figure out how I can set the remote devices settings using MicroPython.

Can you send AT Commands over MicroPython?

Answer (score 0):

Remote AT commands aren't currently supported via the MicroPython interface.  One would typically set `ATNI` and the PAN ID via the local serial interface (or BLE) during commissioning of the network.  But I can imagine scenarios where you'd want to interface with the I/O pins of a remote device.

You'll need to put in a feature request to Digi International to include it in an upcoming release.